# Writing Subscript Values In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string:
`Range("T4").Value = "Rule 13s voilation"`

I want to write `13s` like 1<sub>3</sub><sub>s</sub>
i.e `3` and `s` are a subscript of `1`.

Please suggest on how should I go about it in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: "Tell me how to write the values in subscript in VBA." --> "This question does not show any research effort." That was my call. The OP has asked many questions before and should know this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I see. I appreciate you clarifying that. I am sure OP will now take care in the future. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Range("T4").Value = "Rule 13s voilation"
Range("T4").Characters(Start:=7, Length:=2).Font.Subscript = True
```

I am not sure how this will work for you with dynamic string lengths.

Answer (score 7):

Try doing it manually while recording a macro, and then looking at the resulting code. That will give you your answer.

Here's a cleaned up answer:

```
With Range("T4")
    .Value = "Rule 13s voilation" ' (sic)
    .Characters(Start:=7, Length:=2).Font.Subscript = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to 
concatenate 2 cells into one.
the first one is a text, the second one is a serie of reference to comments

```
Sub setRefWithRemark()


Dim aCellRef, aCellRem, aCelTarget As Range
Dim aRow As Range

For Each aRow In Range("rgtensileRefWithRemark").Rows
    Set aCellRef = aRow.Cells(1, 1)
    Set aCellRem = aRow.Cells(1, 12)
    Set aCellTarget = aRow.Cells(1, 17)
    If aCellRef.Text <> "" Then
        With aCellTarget
           .value = aCellRef.Text & cTextSeparator & aCellRem.Text ' (sic)
           .Characters(Start:=Len(aCellRef.Text) + 2, Length:=Len(aCellRem.Text)).Font.Superscript = True
        End With
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```